# iphone - Can I draw a UIView instance in drawRect?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, drawrect, custom-view

I am trying something like below

```
UIView * view = [UIView new];
view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 50)];
[btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:btn];
CALayer * layer = [view layer];
[layer drawInContext:ctx];
```

My questions is 
 
1) Like we draw images or text with CGContextRef , can we draw a UIView instance the same way ?

I am not so familliar with the core graphics framework , so please let me know the possibilities . My basic aim is to be able to draw custom views in drawRect using CGContextRef by any means .

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method in your subclass of `UIView`. In this method you should draw to the current context.

Comment: Actually my idea is to create a view with buttons and imageViews and then draw this custom view wherever I need . I dont think We can draw a button or something . So I was thinking to achieve it this way but no success yet ...

Comment: @BharatJ: Why would you want to draw a view with buttons as if it were an image? If you want the view and its subviews to show up in your view, add it as a subview.

Comment: @PeterHose: Actually I want to implement page curl effect for my views . All the codes that I downloaded says draw the view ,as in I get the context reference , thats it . For page curl effect you need to draw the views ... But I want to have a different view for every page ... There I am stuck ...